# My tweepy code is just collecting 2 data. I just want to collect more. But I'm not sure whats wrong with my code

Tags: python, twitter, web-crawler

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvrJ6.png)

this code is just giving me 2 data. But it supposed to collect 100.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). You can *edit* your question and replace the images with properly formatted text. See: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) is how to add code block in your question.

Three backticks ``` (CTRL+Enter)  you code block  (CTRL+Enter)```